# Facebook Business and Developer account is on different account

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-business-manager

I have a Facebook Developer account then because Facebook Login required to create a Facebook Business account to verify the business under the Facebook Developer account. But I already have Facebook Business account on different Facebook account different email.

How can I do this without changing API Key or secret on my website or mobile application?

I haven't tried anything yet. Because I'm afraid that, if I verify my business from Developer account then I cannot verify it from my Business account.